# How to make competitive coding solutions more efficient (BIT wise operations)?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-xor, bitwise-or

How do I make my code more efficient (in time) pertaining to a competitive coding question (source: codechef starters 73 div  4):

(Problem) Chef has an array A of length N.  Chef wants to append a non-negative integer X to the array A such that the bitwise OR of the entire array becomes = Y .

Determine the **minimum** possible value of X. If no possible value of *X* exists, output -1.

Input Format
The first line contains a single integer T — the number of test cases. Then the test cases follow.
The first line of each test case contains two integers N and Y — the size of the array A and final bitwise OR of the array A.
The second line of each test case contains N space-separated integers A_1, A_2, ..., A_N denoting the array A.
Please don't judge me for my choice of language .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int* binary_number(int n)     // returns pointer to a array of length 20(based on given constrains)     representing binary 
{
    int* ptc;
    ptc = (int*) malloc(20*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if((n / (int) pow(2,19-i)) > 0){*(ptc + i) = 1;}
        else {*(ptc + i) = 0;}
        n = n % (int) pow(2,19-i) ;
    }
    return ptc;
}

int or_value(int* ptc, int n)    // Takes in pointers containing 1 or zero and gives the logical OR 
{
    for(int k = 0; k < n; n++)
    {
        if(*ptc == *(ptc + 20*k)){continue;}        // pointers are 20 units apart
        else{return 1;break;}
    }

    return *ptc;

}


int main(void) {

int t; scanf("%d", &t);

for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
{
    int n, y;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &y);
    int a[n];
    
    for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[j]);
    }
    
    int b[20*n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
        {
            b[20*j + k] = *(binary_number(a[n])+k);
        }
    }
    
    int c = 0;
    int p = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        
        if ((*(binary_number(y) + j) == 1) && (or_value((&b[0] + j),n) == 0)){c = c + pow(2,19 - j);}
        else if ((*(binary_number(y) + j) == 0) && (or_value((&b[0] + j),n) == 1)){p = 1; break;}
    }

    if (p==1){printf("-1");}
    else {printf("%d\n", c);}
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `malloc` for fixed-sized arrays (whose size is known at compile-time and where the size will remain the same during the life-time of the program). Don't use floating-point functions for integer calculations (like that `pow` call`).

Comment: Start by adopting a readable coding style actually used by a lot of other programmers. Nobody likes to read obfuscated code like this and it will get you fired from any programming job.

Comment: You don't need arrays at all: `unsigned int value = 0;` and then in the loop after reading the value to an `unsigned int a;` do `value |= a;`. After the loop `unsigned int x = value ^ y; if ((x | value) == y) printf("%u\n", x); else printf("-1\n");`.

Comment: Welcome, but competitve programming is no place to learn coding. Those sites are an amusement for people who already know how to code. They encourage bad practices like unwise shortcuts, not validating user input, etc.